# How to get VIP vouchers in another currency?

Tags: lego-store

With the old VIP program, I could simply go in any LEGO store, hand out my VIP card  when paying, and the clerk would tell me how many VIP points I had and ask whether I wanted to use these against my new purchase. No fuss, it was easy for someone like me who doesn't go often to a LEGO store.

Now the whole VIP program changed, and aside from the fact it looks like a complete mess to start with; it seems I can't get automatic discounts in LEGO stores but must first purchase vouchers online with my current VIP points balance. Aside from the fact it's very cumbersome to do so, I face another problem: all vouchers available to me are in GBP, whereas the closest LEGO stores to me are in the Euro zone.

Is there a way to get the rewards center to show me vouchers in EUR? I tried changing languages (which is just about languages and not regions like the regular shop) to French; and both my region selection in the shop and my country selection in my profile are correct (Belgium), but no dice, I only see GBP vouchers. Or would they be accepted in EUR stores?

In general, is it possible to get vouchers in another currency, for example when travelling?

Comment: Sounds like a great question to ask LEGO Customer Service :)

Comment: My vouchers are showing in EUR, and I'm the same country/region as you. Changing language or region does not appear to change anything

Comment: @PhilB. Totally. But it can't hurt to see if anyone else has the issue; in any case when I get an answer from LEGO I'll post it here too.

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve Thanks, I was starting to wonder if they even existed in EUR. I also wonder what happens if you try to use one in GBP to pay for an order in EUR.

Comment: OK, I got some explanation from the Customer Service, it turns out the country linked to my VIP card was the UK - which makes sense considering I'm fairly sure I got my VIP card there (there was no LEGO shop in Belgium or France at the time). So they fixed it; but it's a bit strange that the country for your VIP account and the web account are different. I'll try to salvage the question somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vouchers available in the VIP rewards centre are linked to one's country - that is, the country linked to one's VIP account.

Note that this is not the same as the country of one's account, even though both are linked, and can't be changed online at the moment but only via the Customer Service. There seem to be some kind of redundancy in the way LEGO handles countries and languages at the moment, hopefully they'll fix it at some point. Summary:

- LEGO account (or LEGO.com profile) has a country, which can be changed online (in "Edit Profile" -> "My Information")
- VIP account has a language preference which can be changed online, and a country which cannot

In any case, when facing trouble with anything related to the LEGO website, online shop or VIP centre, it is best to contact the Customer Service directly and they'll do their best to help (and even toss in some extra VIP points for your trouble, which is a rather nice gesture).

At the moment, it doesn't seem possible to get vouchers in another currency except through changing the country linked to the VIP account via the customer Service. This means if you want to redeem VIP points for LEGO purchases, you're in effect limited to do it in your own currency (assuming the vouchers aren't country-specific; haven't tried that yet); but that's probably a minor issue for the majority of people.

Also, shopping in LEGO stores in other countries will get you VIP points without problem - the only subtlety might be that due to exchange rate, you might get more or less points for a similar purchase. As an example, I bought 21319 (Central Perk) in The LEGO House for 649DKK and got 649 VIP points; if I compare that to other countries based on the online shop I get:

- Denmark: 649DKK (~87€), 649 points, so 1 point per 0,1338 EUR spent
- UK: 64,99 GBP (~75€), 520 points, so 1 point per 0,1446 EUR spent
- Belgium: 69,99€, 525 points, so 1 point per 0,1333 EUR spent
- France: 59,99€, 450 points, so 1 point per 0,1333 EUR spent

So the VIP points given when buying a set are tied to the DKK price of that set, and seem to be aligned on exchange rates, with possible the exception of the UK (the online shop notes explicitly that VIP points are calculated at checkout). The difference in VIP points received is probably not worth taking into account when purchasing; however, the price of the set can vary a lot from country to country, and that's worth taking into account.

Comment: I think you've gotten points/€ backwards in the results of the calculations for France and Belgium.

Comment: @Henrik indeed, I mess that up, it's fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: Very useful. Somehow my UK account has the USA as its region so I have been unable to do anything with 23,000 points! Have now contacted Lego customer service